# Can I convert a streamlit uploaded pdf file into a langchain document?

Tags: python, pdf, streamlit, langchain, document-loader

I am building a `streamlit` app where a user can upload a `pdf` file and it generates questions based on the file. The error is the uploaded file is of uploaded_file object and the `langchain`, `pdf` loader accepts the file path as an input stored locally to further load the `pdf` and split it into small chunks of documents using text splitter. Is there a way I can convert it into a `langchain` doc before processing or any other method suitable to do it?

Answer (score 2):

Let us say you a streamlit app with [st.file_uploader](https://docs.streamlit.io/library/api-reference/widgets/st.file_uploader)

```py
import streamlit as st

uploaded_file = st.file_uploader("Upload file")
```

Once a file is uploaded `uploaded_file` contains the file data. You cannot directly pass this to [PyPDFLoader](https://python.langchain.com/docs/modules/data_connection/document_loaders/pdf#using-pypdf) as it is a `BytesIO` object.

We need to save this file locally

```py
with open(uploaded_file.name, mode='wb') as w:
        w.write(uploaded_file.getvalue())
```

and then, pass its file path to the loader

```py
from langchain_community.document_loaders import PyPDFLoader

if uploaded_file: # check if path is not None
    loader = PyPDFLoader(uploaded_file.name)
    pages = loader.load_and_split()
    print(pages[0])
```

`pages` should now be a list of langchain `Document`s

Comment: Possible solution without saving to disk using [PyMuPDF](https://github.com/langchain-ai/langchain/issues/6265#issuecomment-1929210954)